# Jquery Issue with clone - original disappears in some instances

Tags: jquery, clone, hashtag

The script below works well in cloning an element and inserting it at the right place, althought in some cases the original disappears, and I cannot figure out why, could you help figure out if there is something wrong in my code?

The general idea of the script is: whenever there is an ashtag in the Web address (when people post on social medias after clicking on one element), the people that will follow the link will see that element presented at the top of the page. Beside the issue explained above, the script works well.

```
var hashtag = window.location.hash.substr(1);

$(window).load(function() {
    var hashid = ('#' + hashtag);
    if (hashtag ==="") {
        $("#tosee").removeClass("show").addClass("hide"); 
    } else {
        var oritosee = $(hashid).clone(true);
        oritosee.insertAfter('#tosee');
        $("#tosee").addClass("show"); 
    };
});
```

I got a hint from – skobaljic, it was an issue with duplicate ids.

So my solution was to change the cloned id:

```
oritosee.attr('id', oritosee.id + '_' + 'clone');
```

Comment: If they open the page with hashtag, then the browser scrolls down to the elements. That is why you do not need this script at all. On the other side, cloning the element with unique ID is not a good idea, than you create duplicates, which is invalid.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a good point, it could be a duplicate id issue. (I do it this way because the element in question could be burried in a closed div).

Comment: @skobaljic, you were completely right, if y change the id, it works!
oritosee.attr('id',  oritosee.id + '_' + 'clone');

Answer (score 0):

```
oritosee.attr('id', oritosee.id + '_' + 'clone');
```

(Avoid duplicate ids by modifying the cloned element id)